# Dismiss keyboard while other view is animating

Tags: ios, swift, animation, keyboard

My project is very simple, just to explain my question. In the view controller's view, there is a `UITextField` and a `UILabel`. If I touched the label, the label rotate `M_PI`, and the text field resign first responder. If the text field does not become first responder, the label rotate as expected. But if the text field become the first responder and the keyboard appears. When the label is tapped, it jump to the end transform without animation.

I wrote that code in Xcode8, swift 3.0

The code is:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!

@IBOutlet weak var label: UILabel!

func textFieldShouldBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.label.transform = .identity
    }

    return true
}

@IBAction func labelTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) { 
        self.label.transform = self.label.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI))
    }
}
}
```

Comment: you can try put the `resignFirstResponder()` on the `UIView.animate` completion block

Comment: Can the keyboard animation and my animation do at the same time?

Comment: Then you can observe `UIKeyboardWillHideNotification` and add your animation there

Answer (score 0):

Try performing animation after a delay of about 0.5 seconds after the textfield resigns its first responder.

```
func animate() -> Void {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.25) {
        self.label.transform = self.label.transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(M_PI))
    }
}

@IBAction func labelTapped(_ sender: AnyObject) {
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(0.5, target: self, selector: #selector(ViewController.animate), userInfo: nil, repeats: false)
}
```